# Sorting 2d list without sorted() method

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to sort this 2d list

```
arr = [['Potato', 10, 'House'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'], ['few', 4, 'and']]
```

After sorting it should look like this:

```
[['few', 4, 'and'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'],  ['Potato', 10, 'House']]
```

I've tried using minimum number as `arr[0][1]` and then loop through the list but couldn't get it.

without using sorted() nor sort()

Comment: What do you mean by sorting without sort() function? Do you mean that you don't want your original list sorted in-place? Or do you mean that sort() was failing for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

Sort with key argument

```
print(sorted(arr, key=lambda x:x[1]))
# [['few', 4, 'and'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'], ['Potato', 10, 'House']]
```

Answer (score 2):

sorted() works like the other answer, and lists themselves have a sort() method:

```
>>> arr = [['Potato', 10, 'House'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'], ['few', 4, 'and']]
>>> 
>>> arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> arr
[['few', 4, 'and'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'], ['Potato', 10, 'House']]
>>>
```

`sorted()` returns a new sorted list, while `<list>.sort()` sorts the list in place.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this below:

```
from operator import itemgetter

arr = [['Potato', 10, 'House'], ['Salad', 9, 'not'], ['few', 4, 'and']]
print(sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of getting around typing those square braces =)

Comment: Doc on that function says, "Return a callable object that fetches the given item(s) from its operand." So it's returning a callable to get the item, not the item itself. Actually, I like this method. shorter syntax to lambda. thanks. I learned something.

Comment: The `operator` module has other useful functions too that could be used in place of lambda arguments.